# Excel - Rename cell if row contains certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen some similar questions but can't quite find an answer for my situation.  If data is found in a row, then Column C of that row will be labeled with that data.  But I also want all columns below this row to contain this same label in Column C.  Until the next data is found, then I want to repeat the same process for the whole document until every row had data in Column C reflecting the data from its particular section.

I probably did a poor job of explaining that, so here is what I would like to happen.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Example of what I want the outcome to be.]**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which in code look like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Columns("C"), .UsedRange)
            If Left$(Trim(rng.Offset(, 1)), 5) = "Class" Then
                rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            Else
                rng = rng.Offset(-1)
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

If you were to use column D to determine the last row to loop to you might use the following (swop the "D" for a different column letter if you want to use a different column to determine how far to loop to get to last row)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row, "C"))
            If Left$(Trim(rng.Offset(, 1)), 5) = "Class" Then
                rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            Else
                rng = rng.Offset(-1)
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you also for the help and answering a question without me even asking was how would it look in code.  A problem I am having with the code is that it does not stop and keeps running for 1,000's of rows.  I there a way to make it stop if nothing is found in Column E for 3 consecutive rows?

Comment: No worries. Windalfin had already done the thinking. I just translated it into code :-)

Comment: Wow you are fast, I hope you saw my edit before your reply.

Comment: Oops. I just saw your comment!

Comment: This:   A problem I am having with the code is that it does not stop and keeps running for 1,000's of rows. I there a way to make it stop if nothing is found in Column E for 3 consecutive rows?

Comment: Column E since it is the one that will have the 3 or more rows without any data and would be the last row I need to have data in the whole spreadsheet.

Comment: Well you could use as above or try .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row + 3, "C"))

Comment: Let me know how you get on. The current version two (lower) finds the last populated row in D which should be a person's name and uses that as the point to stop at.

Comment: The 2nd set of code works perfectly for me.  Thank you so much!  Can't believe your generosity in helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple with just `IF` formula. 
Here is the pseudocode:

```
if the sentence start with "class" then 
  refer to cell next to him
else:
  refer to cell on top of him
```

[image: Formula view]